# Rooted Verizon S4 on OC1 Accidentally Took the OF1 OTA and Now I'm STUCK

Tags: recovery-mode

I just installed OC1 a few months ago and re-rooted with King Root a month ago.

Everything was going fine until a few weeks ago until I started getting OF1 OTA pop-ups from Verizon.  I was on the stock rom.

Now I never remember hitting the, "yes, please install this and mess up my phone," button but I believe after a while it just installs automatically.  I was very busy Saturday night and finally unlock my phone late Saturday night to have it automatically restart on me and begin to install the OF1 update.

I didn't want to brick my phone so I just let it install and now it gives me a prompt that says, "Android is Updating," after playing the boot sequence audio to a blank screen.  That's it.

Every time I try to go into stock recovery it just installs the OTA again.  I can go into Download Mode but that's it.

Any help is appreciated.  I just want to back up all of my texts, calls and files from memcard0 before I just wipe everything and install a rooted OF1 through Odin like I probably should have weeks ago.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me the other day, except I willingly took the update thinking it was an upgrade to 5.1.1.

I ended up unable to boot...

I suggest using Kies and Smart Switch to force-reinstall android. Know that it will flash OF1, and, you will loose root.

Download mode will work fine using Kies and/or Smart Switch.